# How to set up angular directives that depend on shared objects loaded via ajax?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I apologize in advance if my question sounds naive (I'm an angular noob). But here is my problem:

I have 3 objects loaded via Ajax that are shared across all directives on my page (I made a factory for each of these objects). Let's call these objects A, B, and C. I also have 3 directives that depends on different objects:

- Directive 1 requires object A and B to be finish loading
- Directive 2 and 3 require object A, B and C to finish loading

How do I set up my directives in a way that satisfies this requirement?

Comment: Please add the code so it would be easier to refer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use $q.all(...) to handle multiple promises as if they were one.

In your factories, return the promises that are returned from the ajax call.

In your controller, put the promises returned from the factories onto the scope.

Then in your directives, inject the $q service and wrap the promises passed through in a $q.when(...).then(...) call, adding the promises returned from then() to an array.

Wrap the array in in a $q.all(...), so all promises are resolved as one.

The directive code will look something like:

```
app.directive('directive1',
    function($q){  
        return{
            scope: {
                promise1:'=',
                promise2:'='
          },
          link: function(scope, element, attrs){
              var allPromises = [];
              allPromises.push($q.when(promise1).then(function(value1) {scope.value1 = value1 });
              allPromises.push($q.when(promise2).then(function(value2) {scope.value2 = value2 });

              $q.all(allPromises).then(function() {
                  // code that uses scope.value1 and scope.value2
              });
          }
        }
      }
    ]);
```

You not bother with the $q.when(...) part, but using it will ensure your directive is reusable when the value on the scope is not a promise.

Answer (score 2):

You could resolve promises from your factories in your controller and bind attributes of your directives to the resolved promise values. Then use ng-if to prevent your directives from loading until after the promise values are available.

http://plnkr.co/edit/pBMME4Bdhpif7h4QKnn4?p=preview

```
<!-- Directive markup -->
<div ng-if="factorya && factoryb" directive-a factorya="factorya" factoryb="factoryb"></div>  

//Controller Code
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'factorya','factoryb',

    function($scope, factorya, factoryb){
       factorya().then(function(result){
           $scope.factorya = result;
       });

       factoryb().then(function(result){
           $scope.factoryb = result;
       });

    }

]);

//Directive Code  
app.directive('directiveA', [

  function(){

    return{
      restrict: 'AE',
      scope: {
        factorya:'=',
        factoryb:'='
      },
      link: function(scope){

        alert("Directive A: " + scope.factorya.ajaxResult);

        alert("Directive B: " + scope.factoryb.ajaxResult);

      }

    }

  }

]);
```